# Add Text After Logo in zerif lite theme

Tags: themes

I am tring to add text After logo in the Zerif lite theme. I did this by adding a  after the logo in header.php.

```
echo '<a href="'.esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ).'" class="navbar-brand">';

                        if( file_exists(get_stylesheet_directory()."/images/logo.png")):

                            echo '<img src="'.get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/images/logo.png" alt="'.get_bloginfo('title').'">';

                        else:

                            echo '<img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/logo.png" alt="'.get_bloginfo('title').'">';

                        endif;

                    echo '</a>';

                endif;

            ?>



        </div>
```

DWOKO NEPAL

```
        <nav class="navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse collapse" role="navigation"   id="site-navigation">


            <?php wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'primary', 'container' => false, 'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right responsive-nav main-nav-list', 'fallback_cb'     => 'zerif_wp_page_menu')); ?>

        </nav>
```

I also added custom css as such

```
.section-header x6 {
margin-top=15px
```

I could not get the text Dwoko Nepal to align with the logo and preferably 20 pixels right of the logo.It always sits on top and Pushes the menu down.

I am doing this in localhost,so i do not have a live example to show.

Comment: Please ask this question on your theme Developers forums.

Answer (score 0):

using some custom.css create 2 of these class like

```
#main-nav-fb {
    width: 150px;
    display: block;
    padding: 2px 4px;
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    background: #cc6052;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 200px;
}
```

in header.php

after

```
<div class="navbar-header responsive-logo">
```

add something like this:

```
<a id=main-nav-tel href="tel:+11111111111">+11111111111</a>
```